# Why Intellij IDEA can't recognize defaultEncoding field of ResourceBundleMessageSource class?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have a ResourceBundleMessageSource bean defined in xml file of Spring MVC file. It is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

However, Intellij marks `defaultEncoding` red and pops up `Can not resolve property`.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` has `defaultEncoding` property inherited from `AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource` class. And above code works fine in another Spring MVC project.

My Spring dependencies version is 5.0.4 and IDEA version is 2017.2.1.

What is the reason of such a strange behavior? Is it bug?

APPENDIX: When I decompile `ResourceBundleMessageSource` class with IDEA it shows that this class extends `AbstractMessageSource`, not `AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource` like documentation says.

And replacing `ResourceBundleMessageSource` with `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` gives no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. There was a jersey-spring dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Which was dependent on the older versions of Spring - 3.0.0.RC1 to be exact.
Also I was explicitly including Spring 5.0.4.RELEASE dependencies in the pom.xml file. This was causing a conflict between different versions and Maven was resolving the conflict in favor of the older version 3.0.0.RC1. I decided to delete jersey-spring dependency and now it works fine.